# sale order/create all leads :Can't create Sales Orders

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, trunk, openerp-8

hello user belong to **Sales /create all leads** and can't create sale order for other **Salesperson**

---

admin user can create sale orders of **other** salesperson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded the database using the option

> openerp-server.py -d db --init=sale

Answer (score 0):

There is `ir.rule` object for this. You should delete it (or change).

I don't have OpenERP code now but I hope you will know which `ir.rule` you should change. It has model `sale.order` and group `Sales /create all leads`. Propably there is similiar `ir.rule` for `sale.order.line`.

Comment: thanks brother for answering the ir.rule was fine  :s